# Linux kernel without MMU? for MIPS R3000

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu

I would like to compile the kernel for a MIPS R3000 cpu, but with a more recent kernel. μClinux seems to be integrated into the mainline development.

Now my question, would it be advisable to first try getting a kernel to work under qemu and wich cpu/board would be close to a R3000? Yes eventually I would love to try this for a Playstation1 but there are some other CPU's/boards I want linux for as well and they have similarities to the R3000 and also, no MMU. some sites say the endianess doesn't matter too much: https://www.aurel32.net/info/debian_mips_qemu.php and I hope a compiled kernel would be able to eventually run of the real hardware if I get serial out working at least.

Comment: I don't think Linux is the best choice for non-MMU systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian [dropped](https://www.spinics.net/lists/mips/msg70031.html) older MIPS architecture quite a long time ago. But that's not the worst problem.

Thing is, QEMU itself [isn't](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Qemu#Processor) supporting anything (and never did AFAIK) that ancient either. I was almost going to tell you to just hope finding some more accessible [comparable hardware](http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/MIPS-HOWTO-3.html), but then I found about [SPIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM) and [GXemul](https://astr0baby.wordpress.com/2017/07/07/computer-archeology-ultrix/).

Guess like they all are going to offer you both a FPU and a MMU.. But better than nothing then? Some very 'funny' toy to work with the latter aspect could be a [PSP](https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/PSP) btw.

Also recommended [this doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/nommu-mmap.txt), and the rest of [this discussion](https://www.linux-mips.org/archives/linux-mips/2017-10/msg00372.html) if you are interested to the remainder of the PS1 components and/or mainlining.

EDIT: very basic support was once [proposed](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2014-01/msg00923.html) to QEMU